# How to get UIVisualizer to use the View Model passed to it

Tags: catel

I'm attempting to create view/viewModel pair to act as a MessageBox replacement which will be called by the UIVisualizer Service.   The viewModel has five different constructors, one being the default, and the others to define the different attributes of the MessageBox(e.g. Type, Image, Message, Title, etc.).   I will be creating the viewModel using one of the four non-Default constructors each time I desire a MessageBox to popup.   I am doing this versus using the built-in MessageService is because I'm using third party controls for my application and I want the MessageBox look-and-feel to match the rest of the application.

My problem is that even though I'm creating the viewModel, Catel is not using the viewModel I pass in to UIVisualizer, but is creating a new viewModel from the default constructor.

Does anybody know how to get this behavior to stop.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is create your own version of the IMessageService (create new class deriving from MessageService and override the Show method).

Catel should re-use the passed in view model. If you think you have found a bug, please report it at http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker